# Shakespeare textFileReload has some cache effect?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Here is some code in one of my Yesod handler function:

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy             as LT
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Builder     as TLB

SomeRouteR= do
    -- ................
    code <- someFuncAccessDB
    render <- getUrlRenderParams
    let tmpl = $(textFileReload "templates/some.txt")
        sms_content = LT.toStrict $ TLB.toLazyText $ tmpl render
    $(logDebug) $ "trying to send SMS: " `mappend` sms_content
    -- ....
```

'some.txt' contains some line like:

```
the code is #{code}
```

But the logDebug line reports that 'sms_content' does not change according to the new value of 'code'. That is, when in another new request, event the value of 'code' is changed, 'sms_content' still has the old value of last time it had in the previous request. It seems like Yesod cache the last value of 'sms_content'.

What is my mistake?

Edit: The problem is gone when I change textFileReload to textFile. So I must misunderstand what "Reload" means here. Can anyone give me some clue?

Comment: This behavior may be something to do with [this bug](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/567).